# Is there a way to run a PowerShell script through a JetBrains IDE?

Tags: rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I am currently using RubyMine which is an IDE developed for the Ruby programming language. Although, strangely enough, I find myself executing a lot of PowerShell scripts - something that seems to fall outside the scope of this product.

With some tinkering, I managed to associate **.ps1** files with PowerShell, as well as having the correct syntax highlighting, but I am short one piece of functionality. I would like to run my PowerShell scripts the same way I run my Ruby scripts; through the `Run` menu.

My question is essentially: Is there a way to have RubyMine run my PowerShell script in a new shell, without me having to manually copy/paste the code?

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10249-powershell  Does this help?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe that I missed this plugin when I browsed the repositories yesterday. Thank you, halfelf :)